# pdf reuse .... how to warn if there's an error (rather than just die)

Tags: perl

I am using PDF::Reuse to write a new pdf:

```
use PDF::Reuse;                      
prFile( $copyPdf ); 
prDoc( $old ) ; 
prEnd();
```

works great but if there's an error, the entire script dies...how can I instead just "warn" if Reuse encounters a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in a block [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
use PDF::Reuse;                      

eval {
    prFile( $copyPdf ); 
    prDoc( $old ) ; 
    prEnd();
    1;
} or warn $@;
```

Or better yet, use [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Try-Tiny/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) (it does the same thing but in a safer way):

```
use Try::Tiny;
use PDF::Reuse;                      

try {
    prFile( $copyPdf ); 
    prDoc( $old ) ; 
    prEnd();
} catch {
    warn $_;
};
```

Comment: Don't forget the `;` after the closing brace after `catch`